# php sessions are working fine on live server but not working on localhost?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

There is one live php website which is on live server. Now my work has to change some stylesheet issues. So I just download all the files with the database. I just made setup the site on my localhost(LAMP). When I browse the site on my localhost it just showed a blank screen.Now when I am going through the codes and to check the issues.I can see there are many places session hav been defined. All these session working on live server but not working on my localhost. I have also tried to place

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

on my files top area. But still I am not getting any luck. So can someone Kindly help me to solve this. Any help and suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks

**Update**
Here are the details of the cookies of my live server and my localhost.

Live server Cookie

[image]

Localhost Cookie Info

[image]

Comment: Did you check if there are any special session settings? Maybe `session_set_cookie_params()` is called at some point? If they set a specific domain, you either need to remove the function call or map your LAMP server locally to the desired domain.

Comment: Tell more about the application. Is this CMS , CORE PHP Or MVC ???

Comment: check your php.ini, there should be something like `session.cookie_path` and you may check/point it to a writeable directory (restart apache service after changing that)

Comment: @Deep its a core php project...

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig I have searched the total files and folder there is no session_set_cookie_params() is used..

Comment: blank screen can also mean you're getting a 500 error - can you verify this in a console (or in Firebug)? in such case, it could be .htaccess not working on your local machine perhaps

Comment: @ZathrusWriter yes I have checked that...there is no 500 errors..

Comment: well, then what I do in these cases is simply do `die('abc');` on relevant places - one by one - to see where the *abc* is not displayed on page anymore (like after a file include etc.) and debug the invalid part on its own

Comment: also, did you check your Apache error logs?

Comment: Does the live website run on HTTPS, and are there restrictions that non secure HTTP pages are not delivered?

Comment: @martinstoeckli no the live server don't have https..

Comment: Can you see the session cookie in the browser (live server / local server)?

Comment: @martinstoeckli tell me how can I show you my session cookie? I will show you

Comment: How did you come to conclusion that it is a session issue ?

Comment: It depends on the browser, in Firefox click on the icon left to the domain in the addressbar. Then click the button "More information...".

Comment: @Minesh there are in codes if($_SESSION[''])?> inside that if statement I have tried to echo something. It is not showing the text

Comment: @NewBie I think you should update your answer with some code, that you think is not working and also provide explanation about what you tried. That will give better insight to the problem for all.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I have uploaded the screenshot  for both the cookies  in the question

Comment: @Minesh I have around 1000 files..so how can I share you code?

Comment: @NewBie I am just suggesting you to provide sample code any of 8-10 lines which you think is having problem (session code)

Comment: In your situation, with such a blurry problem, i would make sure that i have a running debugger at hand. Use an IDE that allows to debug, bring it to work with a small independend page, then start debugging this project. In the end it will safe you a lot of time and nerves.

Comment: when I went through error log files I saw an error like `[Fri Feb 08 16:44:15 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/robots.txt`